# Margin does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, margin

I have encountered a very strange behavior of `Margin`..

I want to setup margin like this..

```
circle.Margin = new Thickness(x - radius, y - radius, 0, 0);
```

but the circle is not in the correct position.  When I try to put some numbers instead of variables x and y, the circle stays in position [x - radius, y - radius].

I am using WPF.  When I use this in UWP it worked fine.

I tried to make it alternatively like this

```
circle.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, x - radius);
circle.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, y - radius);
```

but it doesn't work either.. pushes circles to bottom right corner..

Does anybody know where is a problem?

Comment: Can you demonstrate the problem with some screenshot or better description? "not in correct position" and "doesn't work" are poor explanations. Problem might be related to alignment.

Comment: Could you show enough code to illustrate the isse?

Comment: my glasbowl tells me this question should be named "I don't know how margin works and did not bother debugging"

Comment: What is the starting position that you desire? Your code is doing what it says, no bugs there. However, the expectation is not understood. Where do you expect/want the circle to be?

Comment: i put circle shape on image placed in canvas on touch.Position / mouse.Position.. shape is placing on image. I want it to be placed on center  of pointer, it is placed slightly to the right of pointer. when i replaced x or y with value like 50,50 it still puts shapes on pointer position. I have rebuild solution and checked all files, where I use this class.. As I mention I use it in my UWP project written exactly the same and it worked fine. Very strange.. Is there any difference between UWP margin and WPF margin?

Comment: Now it works and didnt changed anything really strange..